# WPF MVVM Tabconrol highlight tab with validation error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, tabcontrol

I'm using WPF MVVM pattern. I have a TabControl with multiple tabs on it
All these tabs are using the same viewmodel. All the validations are working properly and as you can see in the attachement Im showing all the validation erros on a side list view.
here is my xaml code:

```
 <TabControl  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Content" DropDownDisplayMode="Visible" ScrollMode="Item" BorderThickness="0">
        <TabItem  Header="Job Config"  DropDownContent="Job Config" >

            <TabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:JobGroupsCars DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem DropDownContent="Job Info" Header="Job Info">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:JobDetailView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem DropDownContent="Shipping" Header="Shipping Details">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:JobShippingView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem DropDownContent="Controller" Header="Controller">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:ControllerView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem DropDownContent="Ac Motor and Brakes" Header="AC Motor and Brakes" >
            <TabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:ACMotorView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

[image]

my task is when I click on the button in the right panel it has to navigate to the tab with this validation error.

please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know of any propper way to achive this
but judging by the fact you ve been searching for a solution for long i hacked something horrible together for you that will do the trick. 
Add this class first

```
  public static class UIHelper
    {
        public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent, string childName)
        where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                var childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
    }
```

This class will find children by their name. I also put this together to represent your situation:

```
    <TabControl Name="ImTheTabControl">
        <TabItem Name="ImTheTab">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Name="ImTheTextbox"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="ImNotTheTab"/>
        <TabItem Name="ImNotTheTabEighter"/>
    </TabControl>
```

now in your code call this function with the control that contains the error:

```
         void findPapaTab(Control ctrl)
        {
            foreach (TabItem item in ImTheTabControl.Items)
            {
                if (null != UIHelper.FindChild<TextBox>(item.Content as Grid, ImTheTextbox.Name))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks alot , but does this work with MVVM ? or should I put this in the code behind of the user control.

Comment: thats propably not going to work in your viewmodel :/